# WP Multisite Static Frontpage

Tags: multisite, homepage, frontpage, customization

I created a multisite and my question is as followed:

Im trying to display a default static page for each new site.
So when they create a new site, they automatically get a default page I made. This is the only page they need and have controle over. This page has only widgetized area's in it so that the site-admin can add content by adding widgets into the widget area's. They dont have access to create a post or page themselves.

By adding a piece of code into wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php the page will be automatically made by WP whenever a new site is made. However, the page isnt connected to the template with the html/php code in it to display the widgets they add. Normally in WP you can create a page and on the right side you can select a template.

Is it clear this far? (even I get confused lol)

So what Im asking is.. is there a way to create a static frontpage for all newly created sites (like test.example.com and test2.example.com) with a template connected to it?

Thanks in advance!!!
It would make my day!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend waiting until WordPress 3.4 is released. Among other features, [it is slated to include](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19627) the ability to allow Themes to define/declare a static front page. I believe this functionality should suit your needs.

(Note: as of today, [WordPress 3.4 just hit Beta 1](http://wordpress.org/news/2012/04/wordpress-3-4-beta-1/), and is scheduled for final release in May.)

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the creation of a new multisite blog like this:

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'default_settings', 100, 2);
function default_settings($blog_id, $user_id){
    switch_to_blog($blog_id);

    // setup your page here

    restore_current_blog();
}
```

In that function you would use wp_insert_post to create your page, and then you would set the option used to determine the homepage to the ID of the newly created post

Comment: Somthing like:
$pages_to_create = array_diff($default_pages,$temp);

    foreach($pages_to_create as $new_page_title){

            // Create post object
            $my_post = array();
            $my_post['post_title'] = $new_page_title;
            $my_post['post_content'] = 'This is my '.$new_page_title.' page.';
            $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
            $my_post['post_type'] = 'page';  ??

Comment: yeah, though with the insertion call and the closing of the loop etc

Comment: Note that you could also use a home.php template

Comment: how would that work? (the home.php) I know how to create a custom template-page but I guess thats not what you meanth

Comment: refer to the template heirarchy, you have index.php front-page.php and home.php home.php is always the homepage unless you choose a page to be the homepage, front-page.php is the frontpage, aka page 1 of an archive shown by index.php, and index.php is the file used if a file isn't found